# NullPointerException when checking for (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null)

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform, nullpointerexception

I'm new to Parse.com, and am currently building my first project using Parse in Android. I am trying to replicate the login workflow shown in the 'Anywall' tutorial (https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android), but I am absolutely not getting it to work at all.

Whenever I try to launch the app, it gives me a NullPointerException where I am trying to check for (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) in the DispatchActivity (code shown below):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check if there is current user info
        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // Start an intent for the logged in activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        } else {
            // Start and intent for the logged out activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class));
        }

    }
```

The stacktrace in LogCat is as under:

```
07-13 00:34:54.925    6268-6268/com.appzylabs.pratik.groupreceipts W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6142908)
07-13 00:34:54.925    6268-6268/com.appzylabs.pratik.groupreceipts E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appzylabs.pratik.groupreceipts/com.appzylabs.pratik.groupreceipts.DispatchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:304)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.getFromDisk(ParseObject.java:667)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$10.then(ParseUser.java:1056)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$10.then(ParseUser.java:1003)
            at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
            at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
            at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
            at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
            at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:1003)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.access$800(ParseUser.java:26)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$9.then(ParseUser.java:996)
            at com.parse.ParseUser$9.then(ParseUser.java:993)
            at com.parse.TaskQueue.enqueue(TaskQueue.java:61)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserAsync(ParseUser.java:993)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:979)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:966)
            at com.appzylabs.pratik.groupreceipts.DispatchActivity.onCreate(DispatchActivity.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Something tells me that 'ParseUser' is not getting initialized or instantiated properly, but I already have the following code in my Application class:

```
public Application() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "YYYY");

   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Is your ParseUser logged in?

Comment: Thanks, but it was a stupid mistake on my part. figured it out as below.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just realized the problem. I was calling Parse.initialize() in a separate Application class like so:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
...
Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "YYYY");
...
}
```

However, I hadn't added the class to my AndroidManifest.xml so the code was never getting executed, Parse was never getting initialized, and ParseUser was throwing a NullPointerException. Once I added that to my manifest like under, it worked:

```
<application
        android:name="com.appzylabs.pratik.groupreceipts.Application"
```

Sorry about that! I hope this is useful to others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need either to create new ParseUser object and call method `ParseUser.signUp()` or to create new ParseUser with some credentials and call `ParseUser.logIn()` to be able to use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` as long as

> This retrieves the currently logged in ParseUser with a valid session, either from memory or disk if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but it was a stupid mistake on my part. figured it out as below.